# webpack sass-loader not generate class selectors styles

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-sass, sass-loader

I'm using scss into my react application.The problem what i'm getting is when i write css for constant selectors like h1, h2, p, ul, li, its getting accepted. But when i'm write css for class or id selectors, the styles not applying.

**Working case**

```
h1, h2 {
  padding:0px;
}
```

**Not working case**

```
.main {
 padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: share your webpack config please and the part of the react code that is problematic (if possible)

Comment: Is 'modules' flag set in your loader options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS class selector styles not being applied in React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789925/css-class-selector-styles-not-being-applied-in-react-project)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My webpack.config.js looks like this now:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


const config = {
    entry: './app/index.js',
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /(\.css|\.sass|\.scss)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['css-hot-loader'].concat(ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    },
                    {
                        loader : 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader : 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: function () {
                                return [
                                    require("autoprefixer")
                                ];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })),
        },
        {
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use : ['babel-loader']
        }
    ]
},
devtool: 'source-map',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/' // avoid requesting server route instead of client route when hitting refresh /Cannot GET /route
},
plugins : [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'app/index.html'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'css/style.css', disable: true, allChunks: true }), // this means dist/css/style.css
]

};


if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){ // 'production ready'
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env' : {
            'NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        }
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ sourceMap: true, minimize: 
 true })
  )
 }

module.exports = config;
```

I had a `fallbackLoader: 'style-loader'` property before and some unused css-loader options in a query property. Maybe this helps.
The config above works as expected.