# CSS for ReactJS - Referencing a div works fine, referencing a className does not

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, webpack-style-loader

My CSS files work fine when I just use the element names like this:

```
div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

But when I use className to identify that div, the CSS is ignored, like this:

```
.containerInner {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is the js file, so you can see how I'm using className:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styles from './Game.css'
import GameContainer from './GameContainer/GameContainer.js'

class Game extends React.Component {

render() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.containerOuter}>
        <div className={styles.containerInner}>
            <h1 className={styles.header}>MEMORY</h1>
            <GameContainer />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default Game
```

Notes:
1. I am using create-react-app.
2. I am not using modular css like sass. I'm just using raw css.
3. This is a problem throughout my entire project, not just a couple files
4. There are no error messages in Chrome, or in the terminal

This is the same issue on Stack Overflow, but it does not appear to have been resolved on the thread, and the comments did not lead me to a solution. [CSS class selector styles not being applied in React Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789925/css-class-selector-styles-not-being-applied-in-react-project)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a class name to a class, just apply the name.  Class names are strings, not objects;

```
<div className="containerInner">
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Is this a new syntax with the new version of create-react-app? I have dozens of react projects that have all used the syntax from my original question and worked perfectly.

Comment: That syntax is for applying a variable.  If the given variable's value is `"containerInner"`, then it would work identically.  But since you're importing it from a .css file, that seems unlikely.  

I think you may have mixed up where those values were originating from in your other projects.

Comment: if you have time, a followup question: 

Now that the classNames are working, I'm only able to style certain aspects of them.

For instance: 

background-color: blue 

works fine. but...

display: flex;
flex-direction: row:

does not work

Comment: just for the sake of clarity you _can_ use the syntax `className={styles.containerOuter}` however the way you were doing it was incorrect. Unless your css file is a big javascript object?  `{styles.containerOuter}` is referencing an object `styles` with a property `containerOuter`. Just wanted to throw that out, sometimes it is useful to use your originally intended syntax... for example `const currentStyles = user.loggedIn ? 'currentUserStyle' : 'defaultStyle;`  then you can use `className={currentStyles }` <==  that is a super arbitrary example btw, not using a object, but you can use one